# How would I go about combining files using timestamps

Tags: python, python-3.6

OK, so lets assume that both of the files have the same format of time stamp. One file will have a time stamp on every line, whilst the other may have a time stamp then a few lines of information underneath. How would I go about combining the files with the time stamps onto another file so the first file shows that line next to the few lines of the second file.

Using python 3.6 I have tried some methods of this myself but would like someone else's view.

As requested some example almost below:

File1 (with a timestamp on every line)

> Mar 31 12:13:13 xpo3 syslog.info rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.13.0" x-pid="103" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start

File2 (with extra information)

> Mar 31 12:13:13 - UpgradeThread - DEBUG - Started upgrade thread with Process ID: 498
>   WARNING: The prism-j2d pipeline should not be used as the software
>   fallback pipeline.
>   It is no longer tested nor intended to be used for

And so the desired outcome is something like this:

***Mar 31 12:13:13 xpo3 syslog.info rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.13.0" x-pid="103" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start***
*2017-03-31 13:00:39,395 - UpgradeThread - DEBUG - Started upgrade thread with Process ID: 498

WARNING: The prism-j2d pipeline should not be used as the software fallback pipeline.

It is no longer tested nor intended to be used for*

So it takes lines from the files with the same time stamps and writes a new file combing them in an organised fashion.

Many thanks

Comment: Please provide sample inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: @languitar I have made an edit to my question adding information as requested

Comment: @manvi77 I have tried some code where I have using splitline to gather timestamps and attempted to add them to a dictionary which will then be written to a file but I feel this is a bad way and someone out here would have a much better way of going about this